# Finding a longest string in for loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I have the task to write a program in which the user inputs 8 words, after which the program prints the longest word inputed and counts the length of the word. I'm having problems with finding the longest inputed string. Here's my code:

```
counter = 0
for i in range(8):
    x = str(input('Enter a word: '))
    counter = len(x)
if counter == max(counter):
    print('The longest word is: ', counter)
```

which of course doesn't work.

Comment: since I'm new to this website, I don't know how to properly include code, so I just copied an pasted it, and, well, you see how that turned out

Comment: Why do you keep `counter` each time through? Surely you only want to keep it if it is longer than previously?

Comment: Why not keep the word instead of its length? Then at the end you know what the word was, instead of just its length.

Answer (score 1):

`max` can take an argument `key` which is applied to each element:

```
words = [raw_input('Enter a word: ') for _ in xrange(8)]
max_word = max(words, key=len)
```

Answer (score 0):

This ought to do it - this sorts the list using the 'len' operator to obtain the length of each string, and [-1] just picks the last (the longest) one.

```
words = []
for i in range(8):
    words.append(raw_input('Enter a word: '))
longestWord = sorted(words, key=len)[-1]
print 'The longest word is %s (%s character%s)' % (longestWord, len(longestWord), len(longestWord) != 1 and 's' or '')
```

Mind you it is somewhat inefficient in that it stores all inputs in the array until the loop is over. Maybe better would be this:

```
longestWord = ''
for i in range(8):
    word = raw_input('Enter a word: ')
    if len(word) > len(longestWord):
        longestWord = word
print 'The longest word is %s (%s character%s)' % (longestWord, len(longestWord), len(longestWord) != 1 and 's' or '')
```

Answer (score -2):

Consider keeping the lengths in a list and finding the max value in that list.

Comment: :-D same here and your github link

Answer (score -3):

```
counter=""
for i in range(8):
    x=str(input('Enter a word: '))
    if len(counter) < len(x):
      counter = x

print('The longest word is: ',x)
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate it Mr. Wood.

Comment: It will give the shortest word.